# what's the difference between QString and QLatin1String?

Tags: qt

Like the title

> 1.what's the difference between QString and QLatin1String??
>
> 2.when and where do I need to use one of them??
>
> 3.following:

```
QString str;
str = "";
str = QLatin1String("");
```

Is `""` == `QLatin1String("")`??

Comment: *QLatin1String* is a thin wrapper for plain, 8-bit C string.
*QString* is a Unicode-aware string. Under the hood, it stores data as 16-bit characters.
*QString* is a bit more expensive to construct than *QLatin1String* because the data is larger ("Hello" takes up 5 bytes in *QLatin1String*, but 10 bytes in *QString*). However, *QString* is much more powerful so it is used everywhere in the Qt API.

Comment: QLatin1String never allocates memory. So it becomes invalid once the string you passed to it is destroyed.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

QString holds unicode. A string literal "foo" is a byte sequence that could contain text in any encoding. When assigning a string literal to a QString, `QString str = "foo"`, you implicitely convert from a byte sequence in undefined encoding to a QString holding unicode. The QString(const char*) constructor assumes ASCII and will convert as if you typed `QString str = QString::fromAscii("foo")`. That would break if you use non-ascii literals in your source files (e.g., japanese string literals in UTF-8) or pass character data from a char* or QByteArray you read from elsewhere (a file, socket, etc.). Thus it's good practice to keep the  unicode QString world and the byte array QByteArray/char* world separated and only convert between those two explicitly, clearly stating which encoding you want to use to convert between those two. One can define QT_NO_CAST_FROM_ASCII and QT_NO_CAST_TO_ASCII to enforce explicit conversions (I would always enable them when writing a parser of any sort).
Now, to assign a latin1 string literal to a QString variable using explicit conversion, one can use

```
QString foo = QString::fromLatin1("föö");
```

or

```
QString foo = QLatin1String("föö");
```

Both state that the literal is encoded in latin1 and allow "encoding-safe" conversions to unicode.
I find QLatin1String nicer to read and the [QLatin1String docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/QLatin1String.html#details) explain why it will be also faster in some situations.

Wrapping string literals, or in some cases QByteArray or char* variables, holding latin1 data for conversion is the main use for QLatin1String, one wouldn't use QLatin1String as method arguments, member variables or temporaries (all QString).

Comment: "because it doesn't construct four temporary QString objects and make a deep copy of the character data."(From QLatin1String docs),then,doesn't "QString QString::fromAscii ( const char * str, int size = -1 )" construct a object???,why???

Comment: That reasoning looks weird indeed. Looking at the implementation, operator==(const char*) and == QString::fromAscii/Latin1 both construct a full QString, while == QLatin1String doesn't.

Answer (score -1):

QString is Unicode based while QLatin1String is US-ASCII/Latin-1 based

Unicode is a super set of US-ASCII/Latin-1. If you only deal with US-ASCII/Latin-1 characters, the two are the same for you.

http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qstring.html

http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qlatin1string.html